# C++ write to file

Tags: c++, file-io

I have a program which writes to text file.

Example in my textfile:

```
4
QA131 100 100 100 100
QA132 100 100 100 100
QA133 100 100 100 100
QA134 100 100 100 100
```

I want to write a new line which store the record and the 4 will turn into 5.

What is the method used to write to the file?

Here is my code:

```cpp
void inputRecord()
{
    Product product[101];
    char FILENAME[20];

  cout<<"Enter the file you want to open: ";
  cin>>FILENAME;
  ifstream read(FILENAME);
  if (read.is_open())
  {
      while(read.good())
      {
          read>>product[0].line;
            for(int i =0;i< product[0].line;i++)
            {
                read >>product[i].PartNumber 
                     >>product[i].initialQuantity
                     >>product[i].quantitySold 
                     >>product[i].minQuantity
                     >>product[i].price;
            }
             product[0].line+=1;
      }
      read.close();
  }




    ofstream write(FILENAME);
    write<<product[0].line << endl;
             for(int i =0;i< product[0].line;i++)
                {
                    write << product[i].PartNumber << '\t'
                          << product[i].initialQuantity << '\t'
                          << product[i].quantitySold << '\t'
                          << product[i].minQuantity << '\t'
                          << product[i].price << '\t' << endl;
                }
    write.close();

    cout << "Inventory added successfully!" << endl;
    system("pause");
    system("CLS");

}
```

I cannot write the item to the file.

Comment: I'm curious why you're writing out the entire file every time.  I think it would be more efficient to append the new `Product` to the file, and remove the count line.  Get the count inside your `while{}` loop, incrementing your counter with each successful record read until you reach End Of File.

Comment: You haven't posted the part of your program where you add the new item to the product array. Is that the part you are stuck on?

Comment: @john: I noticed that too.  Based on the array declared size of 0 to 100, I'm assuming that adding a new item to the array is not the problem.  But one never knows.

Comment: Question for the poster:  When you say you cannot write the item to the file, what error message are you getting?

Comment: Hi buddies, sorry for misunderstood u all.
My issue: no error message, i can write into file.
but i cannt to input a new line.

Comment: @user2747285 So show the code where you add a new product to the product array. The reading and writing code look (kind of) OK so the error might be where you add the new product to the array.

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't be using a text file for this information?  Perhaps sqlite3 might be worth the effort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could just use fseek to solve your problem.

Here's a really simple example based this [C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/) example

```
#include<cstdio>

int main(void) {
  FILE * pFile;
  pFile = fopen ( "test.txt" , "wb" );

  fprintf(pFile,"00000\n"); // watch spacing

  for (int i=1; i<11; i++) {
    fprintf (pFile, "%d. This line a line of stuff.\n",i);
  }

  fseek(pFile , 0 , SEEK_SET );
  fprintf(pFile,"10   \n"); 
  fclose(pFile);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user2747285 fseek can be used in any file opened in binary mode. There's nothing to stop you writing text to a file opened in binary mode if that's what you want to do.

Comment: glad it helped. Please mark it as answered if that's the approach you used.